# Having problems with reading text of QlineEdit

Tags: qt

I have a QlineEdit with Echomode on password!

Now I want To read and use the thing in the field of the password; this is my code for this part:
    QString Mehdi2 = ui->PassLine->displayText();
    cout<

but in the debug it prints this:
    â—ڈâ—ڈâ—ڈâ—ڈâ—
What should I do to reach the original inserted text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the regular function `ui->PassLine->text()`.